# correct save window buffer to android bitmap?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Currently i'm using the next code for saving image 1920x1080 and it works great:

```
AndroidBitmapInfo info;

void saveBufferToBitmap(JNIEnv *env, ANativeWindow_Buffer *buffer, jobject bitmap) {
    void *pixels;

    LOGI(10, "saving buffer to bitmap");

    if (AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info) < 0) {
        LOGE(10, "Failed to get bitmap info");
            return;
    }

    if (AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels) < 0) {
        LOGE(10, "Failed to lock pixles for bitmap");
        return;
    }

    int i, scan_length;
    scan_length = buffer->width * 4;

    memcpy(pixels, buffer->bits, buffer->width * buffer->height * 4); // 4 = (rgba)

    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
}
```

But it fails to save image 2048x2048 (i mean saved bitmap looks different from buffer image). The only difference i found was different buffer stride value (for 1920 image stride is 1920):

```
Buffer: width: 2048, height: 2048, stride: 2176
```

How should i modify the code above to make it working for 2048 image? Why stride is more than buffer width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few attempts i've found the solution - skip (stride - width) bytes:

```
AndroidBitmapInfo info;

void saveBufferToBitmap(JNIEnv *env, ANativeWindow_Buffer *buffer, jobject bitmap) {
    void *pixels;

    LOGI(10, "saving buffer to bitmap");

    if (AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info) < 0) {
        LOGE(10, "Failed to get bitmap info");
            return;
    }

    if (AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels) < 0) {
        LOGE(10, "Failed to lock pixles for bitmap");
        return;
    }

    int i, scan_length = buffer->width * 4;

    // we need to skip (stride) bytes, not (width) as stride can be > width for some reason
    int scan_skip_bytes = buffer->stride * 4;

    unsigned char *fromBuffer = buffer->bits;
    unsigned char *toBuffer = (unsigned char*)pixels;

    for (i=0; i<buffer->height; i++) {
        memcpy(toBuffer, fromBuffer, scan_length);

        fromBuffer += scan_skip_bytes;
        toBuffer += scan_length;
    }

    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
}
```